# pySVN - fetching list of tags for url given

Tags: python, svn, tags, pysvn

As in the topic, what is the recommended way of fetching list of tags (or simply subdirectories) for the SVN repository URL given?

I'm using pySVN to work with repository.

For example if there is a tree structure like below:

```
trunk/
branch/
tags/
    tag1/
    tag2/
    tag3/
```

how can I get something like:

```
['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
```

?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [`pysvn.Client.list()`](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_client) method?

Answer (score 1):

I have the solution with the following code:

```
from pysvn import Client
import urlparse, posixpath

tagsUrl="svn://MyRepoUrl/tags"
tag_list=[posixpath.basename(urlparse.urlparse(elem[0].get('path'))[2]) for elem in Client().list(tagsUrl)[1:]]
```

Comment: I found that the ls command was needed rather than the list command.